# What's the best way to reverse ssh tunnel to access system behind corp firewall?

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to access a linux server through ssh. Typically this is accessed through a Win2012 jump server using putty. 
I was able to setup a reverse ssh connection in putty from jump server to a AWS VM through HTTP proxy. And this was supposed to forward it to my linux server. But when I connect to my AWS VM and initiate ssh over my remote port, the whole thing just hangs. What am I doing wrong, and is there a better/easier way? No malicious intent, I have physical access to both jump server and linux server. Just bypassing shitty corp firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you did in details ?
Typically on unix systems, for a reverse ssh tunnel, you can do this on your server behind the firewall:

```
ssh -NR ssh_port_AWS:localhost:ssh_port_local_server user@ip_AWS
```

You need to replace

- **ssh_port_AWS** by the port of the distant server that you want to use to access the local server.
- **ssh_port_local_server** by the port of the ssh server of your local server (if you don't change anything, 22).
- **user@ip_AWS** by your AWS connection details (**user@IP**)

Comment: I can't directly tunnel from my linux. I have to connect through a jump server. First i forward all traffic on 443 on my aws to 22. Then in jumpserver putty, I connect to my aws using session hostname user@aws at port 443. Added http proxy in putty connection settings, added auth key by converting my pem key to ppk. In the tunnel section, added a source port 5000 and destination as linux_server:22 then when i hit connect, I get a prompt of my aws server. That works. Now I use my laptop to connect to my aws using ssh, that works too. Then, ssh localhost:5000 which should work, but doesn't.

Comment: It's linux_in_firewall:22 <----5000:win jump putty:443-- http proxy--> aws with fwd rules to 22 <--- laptop should work in theory :)